# What is the difference between the following two codes when using mongo driver in Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, nosql

Currently I'm working on a project, and I'm looking for a better way to source code.
I wonder What is Different,

```
func (db *Database) FindData(ctx context.Context, filter *Data) (*Data, error) {
    col := db.client.Database(DefaultDatabase).Collection(COLLECTION_DATA)

    var data Data
    err := col.FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &data, nil
}
```

and

```
func (db *Database) FindData(ctx context.Context, filter *Data) (*Data, error) {
    col := db.client.Database(DefaultDatabase).Collection(COLLECTION_DATA)


    res := col.FindOne(ctx, filter)
    if err:= res.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var data Data
    err := res.Decode(&reason)

    return &data, err
}
```

What are the possible differences, and which code is better?

Comment: They are equivalent. There is no need to do the longer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified that both sources were the same, and realized that I didn't have to use the long version.

There is no need to implement ERROR processing because ERROR processing of the corresponding result is carried out in Decode().

Thanks for Comment :) Burak Serdar